# Search in sqlite table where column matches regex

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, regex, sqlite

I'm writing a web application in Rails which uses sqlite. I want the user to be able to search a table in the database by using a regex. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes there is a [regexp operator.](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html). But you have to implement the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I use to implement a REGEX function (using PHP and PDO):

```
#to implement regex searches
function php_regex_match ($regex, $str) {
    if (preg_match("/$regex/", $str, $matches)) {
     return 1; #$matches[0];
    }
 return false;
}
$db->sqliteCreateFunction('REGEXP', 'php_regex_match', 2);
```